# Putting iPad in my name

Tags: ipad

I bought my husband an iPad and put 50.00 on it. He doesn't want the iPad so I would like to use. How do I get everything including the credit into my name?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you can't do this easily, at least not through the iPad. I suspect that those $50 are tied to an account in your husband's name? If so, you may wish to contact Apple to see if you can gift that to another account in your name.